# Composition of a continuous derivation and an epimorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, banach-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be Banach algebras and $\varphi$ a continuous epimorphism from $A$ onto $B$. Suppose $D:B\rightarrow X$ is a continuous derivation where $X$ is both a Banach B-bimodule and Banach A-bimodule. 
That is for $m,n\in B$, we have that $D(mn)=D(m)n+mD(n).$

What happens to the composition $D\circ\varphi$? Will it be a continuous derivation also?

I understand that the composition will definitely be continuous since the composition of two continuous maps is continuous. Although I perceive that the composition $D\circ \varphi$ will be a derivation but I cant show how.

I know that for $a,b\in A$
\begin{eqnarray*}
(D\circ\varphi)(ab)&=&D(\varphi(a)\varphi(b))\\&=&D(\varphi(a))\varphi(b)+\varphi(a)D(\varphi(b))\\&=&(D\circ\varphi)(a)b+a(D\circ\varphi)(b).
\end{eqnarray*}

but my question is this: what makes  $\varphi(b)=b\,\,\,$ and $\varphi(a)=a\,\,\,$ from the last two lines above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your epimorphism $\varphi: A \to B$ gives $B$ a structure of $A$-algebra whose scalar multiplication is
$$\begin{matrix}  A \times B & \longrightarrow & B \\
 (a,b) & \longmapsto & a \cdot b &= \varphi(a) b
\end{matrix}$$

In the hypothesis that $X$ is a $A$-$B$-bimodule, left scalar multiplication by $A$ and left scalar multiplication by $B$ are compatible, i.e.
$$\begin{matrix}  A \times X & \longrightarrow & X \\
 (a,x) & \longmapsto & a \cdot_A x &= \varphi(a) \cdot_B x
\end{matrix}$$